# PHP HTML CSS - display image 1:1

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have saved images on the server. They are linked in a database. How can I display the images in a square without cutting them? The images have different proportions of the sides.

I want the image to be displayed square. When you click on it, I want the image to be displayed in the normal shape.

Can anyone help me? (Javascript is also ok).

Thank you!

**extension**

```
<?php

$path = "medien/benutzer/8/";
$dir = opendir($path);
$extensions = array("jpg", "bmp", "gif", "jpeg", "png");

while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
{
    if(in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $extensions))
    {

        echo "<a data-fancybox='gallery' href=".$path.$file."><img src=".$path.$file."></a>";


    }
}


?>
```

it is to be compared with Instagram. The posts in the profile are displayed one after another in a square. If you tap on it, you can view the whole picture.
I have several images in a folder that should be displayed in the same way.

Comment: I assume the database has nothing do with the problem? There are various ways in which a non-square image can be fitted in a square, similar to how, for instance, an image can be fitted on the background of a Windows desktop. It is unclear which way you want to do it. But more importantly, what have you tried yourself? What did your own research turn up? What is the problem that stops you from actually implementing this? Where's the code?

Comment: To respond to your comment, I have expanded my question. Please read there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```css
.image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image" class='background-image: url("/path/file.ext");'></div>
```